# PHP - How to Search about date and get their money total

Tags: php, filtered

My problem is I have a table with a search textbox and I can get specific data from that table using the textbox, at the same time I have another textbox to get the total money of the money column, my problem is when I search for the specific data and after that I try to get the total of the specific data it gives me the total of the whole data in the column, not the filtered data, and I tried to use the queries both at the same time but I couldn't do that,

[This is a Screenshot for the form and the textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O59zy.png)

**Note** I am using the address column in this example just for testing

This is the **HTML with PHP First** code for the **Searching** textbox with the button and table:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
        $search_by_word = $_POST['search'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE firstname LIKE '%$search_by_word%' ";
    }else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
    }
    $query_conn = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>  
        <form action="" method="POST">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                   <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                   <button class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
               </div>
            </form>
            <br><br>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
               </thead>
                <tbody>
                   <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_conn)){
                        $user_id = $row['id'];
                        $firstname = $row['firstname'];
                        $lastname = $row['lastname'];
                        $address = $row['address'];
                        $email = $row['email'];

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>$user_id</td>";
                        echo "<td>$firstname</td>";
                        echo "<td>$lastname</td>";
                        echo "<td>$address</td>";
                        echo "<td>$email</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And here is my **Second** code for the **Total**:

```
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                $query = "SELECT sum(address) AS totalofmoney FROM test";
                $query_conn = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_conn);
                $total = "Total of Salary: " . $data['totalofmoney'];
            }else{
                $total = "Total of Salary: ";
            }  
        ?>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody>
           <?php
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$total</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form action="search_table3.php" method="POST">
                       <div class="col-md-6 text-left">

                           <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sum</button>

                           <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Print</a>
                       </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can't you try to get all the records on the load of the page and then just filtering that list instead of getting the records every time you search?

Comment: Hi @JasperB, I did that, but it will give me the total of the whole data in that column, and I want to get the sum of specific data, because as you see they are two query codes so it will reload the data before getting the sum and here is my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You are not filtering anything in the sum query, you need the filtered data to be in the same form as the sum and add the where clause to the query that you do to the database:

```
$search_by_word = $_POST['search'];
SELECT sum(address) AS totalofmoney FROM test WHERE firstname LIKE '%$search_by_word%'
```

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment  above, and its true, this code is just an example to see what the query is missing